# Application trying to reference incorrect assembly version

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, telerik

I have a application running on a windows server 2012 that was using Telerik.Web.UI.dll `version 2014.1.403.45`. 
During the latest deployment the Telerik dll under /bin folder got updated with `2015.1.401.40`. 
Because of new dll some functionality stopped working. 
When i replace the dll on server with older version i get following error

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2015.1.401.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I also tried to assembly binding

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Web.UI" publicKeyToken="121fae78165ba3d4" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2015.1.401.40" newVersion="2014.1.403.45"/>

        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.4" newVersion="2.1.0.4"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

I am still getiing the same error.

Is there any way to handle this without deplying the entire code again?

Answer (score 0):

i got this type of issue, but in different case(in Unit Testing). for that I cleared the Bin. then did a build. then issue resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a way, but I would redeploy. Build it again with the reference to the older version. That's the safest way and the best way to make sure all references point to the same assembly.

To be absolutely sure about the right references, set the dll to `copy to local` is `true`, and copy and replace it with the one on your server.